# Sqlite database accessing using android studio

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created sqlite db as name kpl by using db browser and paste into mobile internal Storage into one folder like Shivu.

I wrote the code below:

```
public class DbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private  static final int DB_VERSION=1;

    private  static final String DATABASENAME = "kpl.db";

    private  static final String TABLENAME = "User_Master";

    private static final String USER_ID = "id";

    private static final String USER_NAME = "user_name";

    private static final String PASS_WORD = "pass_word";

    private  static final String TABLENAME_1 = "emp_Master";

    private static final String EMP_ID = "id";

    private static final String EMP_NAME = "user_name";



    public  static final String LOCAL_DATABASE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator+"Shivu";



    public String databasePath = "";
    public DbHandler(Context context) {

        super(context,LOCAL_DATABASE_PATH, null, 1);

    }
```

I am getting erro : could not open database,

Please help me as how to i define database folder into code by accessing db.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code to get database exact path

```
 private static String getDatabasePath(Context _context, String _databaseName) {
    return "/data/data/"+_context.getPackageName()+"/databases/"+_databaseName;
}
```

in this method pass context and database name

Comment: Thanks, I have exact path , when i run its work, but i request how to define db path into code. ex: /Shivu/kpl.db

Comment: By above method you can get define  path and if its work for u accpt my answer THanks!

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd parameter is not a path to db, it's a name of your db. The db is expected to be in some well-defined place in your program directory.

Either populate the db by yourself in `SQLiteHelper.oCreate` or if you have the pre-populated db then use this open source library to include pre-populated databases in your apk
https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper